# extjs file upload button alignment change

Tags: file-upload, extjs

Hi i want to align the browse button first and then text area. How to change browse button alignment.
Like,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a button right next to a textfield (textarea?) and after that another button you can use a fieldcontainer.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.form.FieldContainer.html

Here an example:

```
{
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            // The body area will contain three text fields, arranged
            // horizontally, separated by draggable splitters.
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Load from CSV'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                flex: 1,
                name: 'file',
                allowBlank: false  // requires a non-empty value
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Load',
                margin: '0 0 0 30'
            }]
        }
```

And here a working sencha fiddle example

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31je

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi HW_Manuk, thank you for the prompt help, but can't we manage with direct filefield,  I don't want to create 3 components for the simple upload.

Comment: Ahh! That's what you want. To be completely honest I think you either have to do this or write a better fileuploadfield class (Write an extension). I just looked through the documentation again but I don't see any way to move the triggers to the left.
Maybe styling your components using the fieldBodyCls config and selecting the elements like this .trigger-pos-left > .x-form-trigger-wrap > .x-form-text-wrap  and this .trigger-pos-left > .x-form-trigger-wrap > .x-form-trigger will help you